# gnuplot + epslatex: \footnotesize in the plot title leaves much space to the left of the key

Tags: spacing, fontsize, gnuplot, epslatex

As the title said, using `\footnotesize` in `plot ... title '\footnotesize Some Title'` leaves much space to the left of the corresponding key. The space can be annoying with grids.

As you can see in the picture, the space to the left of the keys is even larger with `\footnotesize` than with normal size.

[image: Demonstration of the problem].

Below is an MWE.

`MWE.tex`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\input{test}

\input{test2}

\end{document}
```

`test.gnuplot`

```
set term epslatex color
set out 'test.tex'

set grid
plot sin(x) title '\footnotesize This is a test',       cos(x) title '\footnotesize This is a test',        tan(x) title '\footnotesize This is a test'
```

and `test2.gnuplot`

```
set term epslatex color
set out 'test2.tex'

set grid
plot sin(x) title 'This is a test',     cos(x) title 'This is a test',      tan(x) title 'This is a test'
```

How can this problem be solved? It makes the grid rather ugly (in my taste). Thank you!

Comment: `set key width -5`, adjust the width value

Comment: @giordano Thank you. That works, though some manual work must be done. Post that as an answer please, and I will accept it if no better solution appears in some short time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the [`gnuplot` manual](http://www.gnuplotting.org/manpage-gnuplot-4-6/#Q1-1-458)

> When using the TeX or other terminals where formatting information is embedded in the string, `gnuplot` can only estimate the correctly exact width of the string for key positioning.

So you have to manually adjust the legend width with

```
set key width -5
```

Try different width values to get the best result.

Example:

```gnuplot
set term epslatex color standalone
set out 'test.tex'

set mxtics 15
set grid xtics mxtics
set key width -8
plot sin(x) title '\footnotesize This is a test',         cos(x) title '\footnotesize This is a test',         tan(x) title '\footnotesize This is a test'
```

> [image]

Comment: Good reference! That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, is there a way other than `\footnotesize` to get smaller keys?

Comment: @ftfish smaller than `\footnotesize` there are `\scriptsize` and `\tiny`.  Remember to adjust the width of the legend accordingly when you change the title of the plots.

Comment: No, I meant whether there is any built-in method/keyword/function in gnuplot to change the key font for epslatex terminal, i.e. not using latex in strings.

Comment: @ftfish the standard way to set the font size in `gnuplot` is `set key font ",<size>"` (see the manual), but this seems to have no effect with the `epslatex` terminal.

Comment: I'm aware of `set key font` which, as you said, doesn't work for `epslatex`. But thanks anyways, I now gain more confidence that there's no other way around.